# Stop jvm from commandline for gracefull shutdown

Tags: java, jvm, shutdown-hook

I am doing some Poc for [Stilts stomp server](http://stilts.projectodd.org/). Need to prevent server jvm termination and do it through another jvm. Here is a code snippet

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        log.debug("Starting server...");
        StompServer<MockStompProvider> server = new StompServer<MockStompProvider>();
        server.setStompProvider( new MockStompProvider() );
        server.addConnector( new InsecureConnector() );
        server.start();
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(200000);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception ", ex);
    }
}
```

There are two requirements.

1. Is there any other way to prevent termination the above jvm without using `while` loop.
2. I would like to stop jvm using command like `java -jar server.jar -- stop` for example a server like [jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/start-jar.html). Jetty use ports and listens for signal for stop request. Is there any simple way.

One option for second one can be using a AnchorFile, create file when start jvm and monitor for file existence and using stop jvm remove that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with ServerSocket

```
static final int PORT = Integer.getInteger("port", 65432);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
        new Socket("localhost", PORT);
        return;
    }

    try {
        log.debug("Starting server...");
        StompServer<MockStompProvider> server = new StompServer<MockStompProvider>();
        server.setStompProvider( new MockStompProvider() );
        server.addConnector( new InsecureConnector() );
        server.start();
        new ServerSocket(PORT).accept();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception ", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: @vels4j you can improve the error handling. e.g. detect that the service is already running and give a reasonable error if you stop without a running service.  Note: this will stop if you connect from any machine ( you could check the source IP)